# Cannot resolve symbol 'GoogleApiClient' after adding the Firebase dependency

Tags: android, android-studio

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
```

After I added this dependency, the problem occurs. Before that, the `GoogleApiClient` works fine. I remove that dependency, the problem is solved. Do `GoogleApiClient` and Firebase have conflict about each other? Please help.

**EDIT:** Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "application.id"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
}
```

Comment: post your gradle

Comment: I added my gradle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GoogleApiClient and firebase-database will work, if you add below dependencies,

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
```

firebase-database dependency will not affect GoogleApiClient

**Please keep same versions for firebase & Google Play Services API(10.2.0)**

Please re-check you have set up everything as below guidance,

https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup